# How to set image to right edge corner in UIButton in/after iOS 15? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uibutton, ios15

I'm facing an issue in iOS 15 where when setting the image to the right corner doesn't work while before iOS 15 it is working properly.
What I want to achieve:
[image: ExpectedResult]

What I'm achieving:
[image: ActualResult]

Here is the complete code which I'm using for iOS 15:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController { 
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let btnDropdown = getDropdownButton()
        btnDropdown.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btnDropdown)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btnDropdown.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
            btnDropdown.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            btnDropdown.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            btnDropdown.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30)
        ])
    }
    
    fileprivate func getDropdownButton() -> UIButton {
        var button: UIButton!
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *),
           let btnConfig = getButtonConfiguration() {
            button = UIButton(configuration: btnConfig)
        } else {
            button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        }
        button.setTitle("Select Tags", for: .normal)
        setupGeneralSettings(for: button)
        return button
    }
    
    fileprivate func setupGeneralSettings(for button: UIButton) {
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.backgroundColor = .lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    }
    
    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    fileprivate func getButtonConfiguration() -> UIButton.Configuration? {
        var btnConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        btnConfig.buttonSize = .medium
        btnConfig.titleAlignment = .leading
        btnConfig.imagePlacement = .trailing
        btnConfig.image = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.circle")
        btnConfig.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8)
        btnConfig.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
            var outgoing = incoming
            outgoing.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
            return outgoing
        }
        return btnConfig
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** *When I say iOS 15, I mean that I'm using UIButton.Configuration because as the UIButton's titleEdgeInset, imageEdgeInset & contentEdgeInset is deprecated in iOS 15.
Also, I think there is something I'm missing in UIButton.Configuration by which the image will get to the right edge of the button but I'm not sure what it is.*

Please let me know if there is any other information that's needed.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *may* be running into issues by mixing *some* old-style button code with the new `.configuration` style, however...

Change this line in `setupGeneralSettings()`:

```
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

to this:

```
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
```

and see if you get the desired layout.

Comment: Damn! You got me! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can add an external image like that:

Under your controller class, declare your objects:

```
let btnDropdown = UIButton()
let myImageView = UIImageView()
```

In viewDidLoad (or in a function) set objects attribute and constraints:

```
    myImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.circle")
    myImageView.tintColor = .systemBlue
    myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    btnDropdown.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    btnDropdown.setTitle("Select Tags", for: .normal)
    btnDropdown.layer.borderWidth = 1
    btnDropdown.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor // here set your border color
    btnDropdown.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    btnDropdown.clipsToBounds = true
    btnDropdown.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    btnDropdown.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btnDropdown.configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    btnDropdown.configuration?.background.backgroundColor = .lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    btnDropdown.configuration?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
      var outgoing = incoming
      outgoing.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
      return outgoing
     }

    view.addSubview(btnDropdown)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        btnDropdown.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
        btnDropdown.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        btnDropdown.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        btnDropdown.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30)
    ])
    
    view.addSubview(myImageView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        myImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnDropdown.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
        myImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnDropdown.topAnchor, constant: 8),
        myImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnDropdown.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
        myImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28) // 28 is the result of difference from 44 (the height of button) and the sum of padding top + padding bottom (8 + 8): 44 - 16 = 28
    ])
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That is an option we can do but I was wondering if are there any properties inside UIButton.Configuration by which we can achieve this instead of adding an image inside the button.